# Android use Expandable List View

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am new in Android . I want use Expandable List View Fragment class >>

this is my fragment class

```
import om.hct.muscat.R;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class AbouthctFragment extends Fragment {

    public AbouthctFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_hct, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your issue exactly?

Comment: I want to use Expandable List View in my app

Comment: Then who prevents you to use? Any particular issue you are facing? or if any confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this tutorial , it is very helpful

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/